# Setting html base root by finding accurate containing word inside link

Tags: html

I wonder if there is any way to search in href for specific folder name and then set it as default base of html document.

> For example:
>   C:\Users\randomuser\Desktop\website\page1\page2\page3\page4\
>
> I want that everytime i create new page, the default root would be
>   \website\ for every html file inside directories after \website\
>
> So that i won't need to write alot of ......\
>
> I just want that all the pages could have link to default page without
>   changing link itself in any way.

**IMPORTANT: do not involve anything other than html (that means no php, javascript ETC. )**

Answer (score 1):

`base`-Tag will help:

```
<head>
    <base href="yourbase">
</head>
```

Comment: Yeah, i get it, i know that there is base tag, thing is when  i move the html document to upper directory, i need to add ..\ everytime. I get bored of adding them cause there is alot of subfolders inside subfolders. I need solution for that. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: Imagine your base is /website/ and you're in /website/monkey/giraffe/xyz.html, then if you link to index.html it will be /website/index.html.
Now you're in /website/bee/honey.html and base is again /website/, then it'll be also /website/index.html.
No need for ../ anywhere.

Comment: Ah, I know what it could be: Do you try to access those files without web server?
Then use something like file:///<yourpath> as base href. This is very ugly, you should use a web server.

Comment: yes, i try to access it without web server, i need it to be the same with and without webserver. From what you are posting it is seems to be hard to achieve or even impossible, well maybe that is why i posted this thread here. Maybe someone is having some kind of Base PATH syntax witch could search for the /website/ in inside file:///<yourpath>

Comment: and set it as BASE. I'd be glad if someone could try to make my question more accurate, so that more people could be involved in resolving this, if it is not sounding pointless thing already. Well, for me that be awesome handy thing. Cause structure of the site could be easier to manage.

Comment: You can't do that with html solely then.